# ExpressionEngine SafeCracker Form Does Not Submit and Simply Refreshes Page

Tags: expressionengine

I have the following contact form, but it does not seem to be submitting when I have completed all of the fields as required. The page just refreshes to show the same form with the data filled in.

```
{exp:safecracker channel="contact_us" id="form-contact" return="contact-us/thanks" datepicker="no" error_handling="inline" include_jquery="no" rules:cf_contact_us_email="valid_email"}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your contact details</legend>

        <ul>
            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_title}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_title}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_title}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_title}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_name}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_name}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_name}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_name}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_address}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_address}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_address}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_address}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_towncity}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_towncity}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_towncity}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_towncity}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_postcode}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_postcode}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_postcode}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_postcode}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_telephone}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_telephone}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_telephone}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_telephone}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_email}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_email}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_email}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_email}</li>{/if}

            <li class="inset"><label>{label:cf_contact_us_method}</label></li>
            <li>{field:cf_contact_us_method}{if required} *{/if}<br>{error:cf_contact_us_method}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_method}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_method}</li>{/if}

            <li><label>{label:cf_contact_us_enquiry}</label>{field:cf_contact_us_enquiry}{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_enquiry}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_enquiry}</li>{/if}

            <li class="checkbox-first">{field:cf_contact_us_terms} <a href="{site_url}/terms}">Terms and Conditions</a>{if required} *{/if}</li>
            {if error:cf_contact_us_terms}<li class="error">{error:cf_contact_us_terms}</li>{/if}

            <span class="clearfix"></span>
            <li class="form-button"><input type="submit" class="submit rounded" name="send" value="Send" /></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
{/exp:safecracker}
```

I wondered if anyone might be able to help me figure this out. It’s likely something incredibly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `error_handling="inline"` [parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/usage.html#par_error_handling), which will allow you to see the actual error message(s) SafeCracker is presenting to you thru the [User Message Templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/message_pages/index.html#user_message_template).

In looking over your code, your SafeCracker form seems to be missing the Title `{title}` field, which I believe is required by SafeCracker — either thru a hidden input or supplied by the user.

To troubleshoot your SafeCracker form:

1. Remove the Error Handling Parameter
2. Include the Entry Title Field `{title}`

Doing this will allow you to:

- See the Full Error Message
- Submit the Entry to ExpressionEngine

Once you have everything working, you can change the error handling parameter back to inline.

Comment: Thank you so much. The current usage guide on the ExpressionEngine site does not mention that the title field is required.

Comment: I noticed the same thing, too. I've submitted a bug report to EllisLab to include a note in the Documentation about the `{title}` being a required field for SafeCracker forms.

Comment: Seems a bit strange that you would need to add a title field for a contact form. I have included it as a hidden input now but it would be ideal to have something dynamic from the name entered in the form.

Comment: It makes sense that the `{title}` field is required, since SafeCracker is meant to allow users to *submit entries* into ExpressionEngine from outside the control panel. It's a shame the documentation isn't more clear about this. However, for the purpose of a contact form – *where a `{title}` for the content doesn't make sense* – most people use the [Solspace Freeform Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) or the simple built-in [Email Module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/email/) instead of SafeCracker.